# How to implement login using SHA-256 algorithm based Digest authentication in JAVA

Tags: java, authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x, sha256, digest-authentication

I'm trying to implement a Digest authentication based login using SHA-256 algorithm in java, but not getting much help. I'm able to login using POSTMAN and getting HTTP status code 200, but not sure how POSTMAN has used the SHA-256 here, Postman request config snapshot and My implementation below, which throws SSLHandshakeException. [image]

Here's my code using which I'm getting Handshake failure :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.DigestScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.*;

import junit.framework.Assert;

public class DigestTest {

    private static final String URL = "https://10.0.1.190/API/Web/Login";
    private static final String USER = "admin";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "testing123456";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        new DigestTest().run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,SSLv3");

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

        HttpHost target
                = new HttpHost(httpPost.getURI().getHost(), 443, "https");
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

        UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials
                = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(USER, PASSWORD);
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort()),
                credentials);

        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient
                = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();

        try {

            DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();

            digestAuth.overrideParamter("qop", "auth");
            digestAuth.overrideParamter("nc", "0");
            digestAuth.overrideParamter("cnonce", DigestScheme.createCnonce());
            digestAuth.overrideParamter("algorithm", "SHA-256");

            AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
            authCache.put(target, digestAuth);

            HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
            localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);

            CloseableHttpResponse response;

            response = httpclient.execute(target, httpPost, localContext);
            Map<String, String> wwwAuth = Arrays
                    .stream(response.getHeaders("WWW-Authenticate")[0]
                            .getElements())
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(HeaderElement::getName,
                            HeaderElement::getValue));

            // the first call ALWAYS fails with a 401
//            Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), 401);

            digestAuth.overrideParamter("opaque", wwwAuth.get("opaque"));
            digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", wwwAuth.get("nonce"));
            digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", wwwAuth.get("Digest realm"));
            Header authenticate = digestAuth.authenticate(credentials, httpPost,
                    localContext);
            httpPost.addHeader(authenticate);

            response = httpclient.execute(target, httpPost, localContext);

            // the 2nd call is the real deal
//            Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), 200);

            //System.out.println(IOUtils
              //      .toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "utf-8"));
            System.out.println(response.getEntity().getContent().toString());

        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception : \n"+e);
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }

}
```

I'm getting the exception below :

> Exception :
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Please help with the code rectification.

Comment: Example of Digest client implementation with native `java.net.http.HttpClient`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76750652/2073804

Answer (score 0):

In postman you can export your request to a code snippet (see https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/ how).

In your case, the java snippet using the `OkHttp` client will be:

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://test.it/uri")
  .method("POST", body)
  .addHeader("Authorization", 
             "Digest username=\"username\", realm=\"test\", nonce=\"nonce\", uri=\"/uri\", 
             algorithm=\"SHA-256\", 
             response=\"6d46e1187d1e79c88241d4ae0e57eda1cd572dfb027ce9eded02aea499f15695\""
  )
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

*(Notice that you need to replace the `username`, `realm`, `nonce` and `uri` with your actual values.)*.

To compute the `response` value, you can see the formula (for MD5) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication.

In the code above the computation with SHA256 instead of MD5 is the following:

```
HA1 = SHA256(username:realm:password) = SHA256(username:test:password) = 338c3ad443d25c378fdcdb90df9f81d42161278b8f1f03276a2d14f0803165f2
HA2 = SHA256(method:digestURI) = SHA256(POST:/uri) = fc51c21830fc2b6ffe97afe3290df89e7c2b1e287d6e373ad4282ce7fe912650
response = SHA256(HA1:nonce:HA2) = SHA256(338c3ad443d25c378fdcdb90df9f81d42161278b8f1f03276a2d14f0803165f2:nonce:fc51c21830fc2b6ffe97afe3290df89e7c2b1e287d6e373ad4282ce7fe912650)
= 6d46e1187d1e79c88241d4ae0e57eda1cd572dfb027ce9eded02aea499f15695
```

Comment: While this is helpful, OP is using `HttpClient` and not `OkHttp`.

Comment: Thanks @Andrea , I've tried using OkHttp but not able to fetch response headers such as nonce, opaque, etc.

Comment: I don't think that is related with the authentication but with the certificate from your service